# React Js render list item element inside list

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to map a `<li>` element to my `<ul>` list.

```
makelist: function () {
    var self = this;
    return _.map(this.state.files, function (val) {
        return React.createElement('li', { key: val.id }, React.createElement('p', { className: bgSuccess }, val.name, ' ', delButton), progressBar, errorDiv);

    });
},
```

In my return statement I'm invoking the method:

```
return (
        <div className='file-input-controls'>
            <ul className='file-input-list'>
                {this.list()}
            </ul>
            <TableActionButtons {...actionButtonsOptions} />
        </div>
    );
```

Obviously the `ul` shows regardless, how can I only show the list if there are list items?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the size of the list items before you actually create the `ul`.

```
var ul = null;
var items = this.makelist();
if (items.length > 0) {
    ul = (
        <ul className='file-input-list'>
            {items}
        </ul>
    );
}

return (
    <div className='file-input-controls'>
        {ul}
        <TableActionButtons {...actionButtonsOptions} />
    </div>
);
```